# Using Google Sheets Menu with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-analytics-api

I am new to Google Apps Script and looking for some insight into a feature I would like to implement.

I am using the Google Analytics add-on inside of Google sheets to report on our site. I have already set up a script to send out daily reports, but currently still have to run the reports manually using the add-on. Is there a way I can access the add-on menu using Google Apps Script?

I'd like to add the functionality of clicking 'Run Reports' in the GA add-on menu before my daily email script. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you mean is you're inside a sheet, and you want to be able to press Add-On->Add-on Name to run the report.

You're not able to do this unless your script is a published Add-on available on the add on store for anyone to download. [Given the restrictions Google currently has in place for that](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish), it's unlikely you'll want to do that.

Instead, you want to create a custom menu. An example found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus). I'm not going to bother copy/pasting their sample, as I'd be leaving it as is.

From the sounds of it though, you might prefer to create a time based trigger. The simplest way to do this is open your script, press 'Resources' -> Current projects triggers -> 'Click here to add one now'. This will allow you to set a time based trigger to run every day for example.